# Screen off to trigger shut down on Android

Tags: android

When an Android device's screen turns off, I would like to shut down the device after 6 hours. I have a customized Android OS and I want to make changes to the Android source code to make this happen. Do you know which framework or module has the logic for 'screen off' and 'power off/shut down' in the Android source code? Thanks a lot!